# What application is used to run cmd scripts?

Tags: windows-xp, group-policy, scripting, windows-command-prompt

I am creating an application whitelist in a local group policy and need to be able to run cmd script files. Simply adding `cmd.exe`, `wscript.exe`, or `cscript.exe` to the whitelist does not effect anything. my script files have the `.cmd` extention. Is there a different application that handles `.cmd` script files?

Comment: As far as I can tell from this discussion it's cmd.exe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148968/windows-batch-files-bat-vs-cmd

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The binary `cmd.exe` is the default interpreter for `.CMD` files.

As the file extension `CMD` is listed as a default Designated File Type in a Software Restriction Policy, you will need to whitelist the `CMD` files themselves, not just `cmd.exe`.   You can do this by either creating a path rule to allow just specific, or all, `CMD` files.

If you want to allow *any* `CMD` to run from anywhere, you may also remove the `CMD` entry from the Designated File Types dialog.  This will allow SRP to skip processing these file types.

[image]

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you for the excellent explanation as well, always helps to understand something.